# Who was Arishtanemi?

Tags: puranas, rig-veda

I was watching lakshmi Narayan 1951 movie, Laxmi reincarnates on earth as bhuvan Mohini, while purandar indra and his enemy cousin Arishtanemi try to abduct her, then Arishtanemi with help of vritra, kicks out devas along with indra out of heaven. Then indra goes to Dadhichi maharishi to learn Brahma vidya. So who was Arishtanemi, is he son of vinata, mother of danava, vasuki/sarpas? And where is his and purandar indra's story told?

Comment: Garuda, but i didnt know about purandar indra story not sure why would Garuda abduct Laxmi

Comment: [This](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/arishtanemi) may help you to find out the character you're looking for.